# host node module on local server and install them in application using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working on creating a node package which has this structure:

```
my_module(folder)

--package.json (inside the my_module folder)
--other files/folder (inside the my_module folder)
```

The package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my_package",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Test Package"
}
```

I am packaging this in my_package.tgz format and hosting that file in my local tomcat server http://url_to_server/my_package.tgz . I can download the file using this url.

In some local application I am trying to install that package using `npm install "http://url_to_server/my_package.tgz" --save-dev` and it throws error saying that it is not a package. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had problem in packaging the the files in folder .I packaged same folder using this command.

```
tar -zcvf source-folder-name.tar.gz source-folder-name
```

and I was able to download and install properly.